# Enable JavaScript syntax highlighting for questions tagged with [meteor]

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Just as with [node.js questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123146/syntax-highlighting-javascript-node-js), a question which is not tagged with [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) but [meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meteor) should use JavaScript syntax highlighting by default.

[meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meteor) is a [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) framework, and all Meteor code is JavaScript code.

Comment: Your initial comment seems to imply that *currently* questions tagged node.js do have javascript highlighting (and it seems you are using this as a support argument). However from the comments to the question you linked it seems as if this *is not the case*.

Answer (score 15):

**Please no**. Those are special cases, and allowing some of them will only trigger more requests in the future (e.g. what about [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs)? why not do the same for python's highlighting to [numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy) questions? In general why don't we do this for *every* framework for *every* language out there?).

Also there are less than 6000 questions tagged [meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meteor) while there are more than 650k questions tagged [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript). There are a lot of questions tagged with both tags, and also a lot of questions that don't have the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag but that also *don't contain code*. So I don't think that there's any real problem in the first place.

Just remember to always add the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) when your question contains code written in it.

Comment: `<!-- language: lang-js -->` FTW!

Comment: There are some [4k questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meteor+-javascript) tagged with [tag:meteor] and not [tag:javascript]. Of the first 50, only 3 had five tags. From 51-100 and 101-150, there were 1 each. Adding the [tag:javascript] tag seems like an excellent solution if people want proper highlighting, and in the rare cases where that isn't possible the manual language markup should be enough.

Comment: What if there was some way for the community to associate framework tags with their languages? It could be a system similar to tag duplicates: someone with high rep could indicate that `meteor` is a tag that uses `javascript` syntax highlighting, for example. This would allow the system to scale well without adding more work for moderators.

Comment: @Kevin I don't see how that would provide any real benefit. I'd rather let SO devs do something else instead of wasting time adding a feature that is pretty much useless. If a question contains code you should already tag it with the language tag, and that already solves the problem of highlighting. In the *extremely rare* circumstance where your question already needs 5 tags *more* than the language tag you can follow Braiam suggestion and highlight explicitly.

Comment: @Bakuriu: do you realize how naive "Just remember to always add the `javascript` when your question contains code written in it." is? It's not *me*, a dude who apparently wastes his time on MSO trying to make life easier for new StackExchange users, asking those questions. It's those new StackExchange users who, I guarantee you, will *not* think of adding the JavaScript tag to a question about Meteor.

Comment: @Dan Dascalescu: a better usage of time is to retag questions when needed and tell new users to properly tag their question in order to have syntax highlightning. It seems obvious to me that if your question contains JS code it should be tagged as Javascript, whatever the framework you are using is.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, please.**

[Here's a sample [meteor] question without code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257958/server-cleanup-after-a-client-disconnects?lq=1) that would benefit from JavaScript code highlighting for its answers.

Comment: Added the missing [tag:JavaScript]. Problem solved.

Comment: @Deduplicator Thank you, have another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34062702/meteor-publish-subscribe-best-practice

Comment: So, why didn't you just fix it?

Comment: @Deduplicator I dislike menial tasks that should be automated.

Comment: So, dig out one of the proposals for a tag-hierarchy then. Adding syntax-highlighting to badly tagged questions this way only treats one of the symptoms of mis-tagging.