# Shouldn't [ruby-on-rails] have ruby highlighting?

Tags: feature-request, tags, syntax-highlighting

[ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) (203K) currently has a highlighting-hint of *default* instead of *lang-rb*, as [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) (only 133K) itself has.

Please change it to *lang-rb* too.

Comment: Does RoR have a template language associated with it? Or is the majority of code in such questions Ruby code?

Comment: What about commands that are specific to the generators and their output?  Why should those be highlighted in code syntax?  I've found a few examples which *don't* include Ruby code and wouldn't make sense to have colored.

Comment: Isn't this the same as [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266751/510937) question? The consensus seemed to be: no, frameworks should not have language highlighting. Just add the [tag:ruby] to the question to get that. The language tag *should* be included anyway.

Comment: @Bakuriu as a heads up, there's there's 142K questions tagged ruby-on-rails but not tagged ruby. That means that the majority of Rails questions aren't tagged with Ruby.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I don't see your point. It simply means that either the community of rails is ok with the default highlighting, or that they are simply mistaggin their questions. If you start editing and prompting people to correctly use the tag that may change.

Comment: @Bakuriu My understanding of the convention used by we Rubyists here is that pure Ruby questions get the [ruby] tag.  Questions involving ruby-on-rails get that tag, but not the [ruby] tag.  This has helped me in my searches here (I'm a Ruby programmer, but not a rails programmer).