# Tag language hint association request for meteor

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, syntax-highlighting

> Per the [introduction of tag specific hints to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72082/209031), and [how to add (or suggest) a tag language association for syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297101/1366033).

Can the default language for [meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meteor) be `lang-js`?

It's an entirely JavaScript based platform and most questions are likely to revolve around the usage of javascript code.

Here's are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31655233/1366033) [recent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31649573/1366033) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31649573/1366033) [where](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31637142/1366033) [defaulting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31634620/1366033) the language would be helpful.

Comment: Might you also add a section about why tagging with javascript wouldn't be right?

Comment: related, if not a duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266751/enable-javascript-syntax-highlighting-for-questions-tagged-with-meteor